# about tf.repeat().batch(batch_size)

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

I am studying tensorflow.
About repeat function in tensorflow.data.Dataset, if there is no argument in the repeat function, repeat(), the tensor should be repeated indefinitely.
however, when the repeat function without an argument is combined with batch function under loop statement, it created a result without endless repetition as shown below.
I could not understand the process.
could you explain the repeat function using the example below?
thank you!

```
for count_batch in ds_counter.repeat().batch(10).take(10):
  print(count_batch.numpy())

[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
[20 21 22 23 24  0  1  2  3  4]
[ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]
[15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
[20 21 22 23 24  0  1  2  3  4]
[ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]
[15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `.take(10)` as the last chained method, so the resultant dataset gets limited to only 10 samples because of that. A single `sample` here will be all elements in a single batch. There are unlimited repetition of 10 batches out of which you are taking an initial 10 of them using `.take(10)`.  Changing your code to below should give you the expected outcome.

```
ds_counter = tf.data.Dataset.range(25)
for count_batch in ds_counter.repeat().batch(10):
    print(count_batch.numpy())
```